# Checking if cursor is in certain radius

Tags: c#, geometry

actually I'm trying to do a program which tells if you are in my secret radius or not.
 I'd set a Point to for example **x** = 1000 and y = 400, and I'd set the radius to for example 50, if my cursor is in radius of 50 from the point, it will write into the console "you are in the radius, x is 1000 and y is 400".

**This is not a homework or anything similiar, I'm just trying something new.**

Ok, so here is what I tried and can't move on anymore.

-NOTE: the radius is supposed to be circle, so I'd guess I need to implement *r* and *PI* but I'm not so sure how to do it programmatically:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out System.Drawing.Point point);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);

    static void Main(string[] args){
        Point cursorPoint;
        Point myPos = Point.Empty;
        myPos.X = 1000;
        myPos.Y = 400;
        int myRadius = 50;
        while (true){
            //if pressed ESC let me end the program.
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Escape) > 0)
                return;
            //get cursor pos and store it in cursorPoint
            GetCursorPos(out cursorPoint);

            //here should be a check with some calculation about radius, but I can't do that..
            Console.WriteLine("You are in radius and your cursor coordinations are X:{0}|Y:{1}",cursorPoint.X,cursorPoint.Y);
            //help cpu
            Thread.Sleep(16);
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's a math question. Distance = sqrt[(x2−x1)^2+(y2−y1)^2]

Comment: is this a winforms or wpf project?

Comment: console application with winforms as reference

Comment: @Szer it might be math question but still, i dont have a clue how to check if my cursor is in the radius of your formula, thats the biggest problem here

Comment: @dadasdasdas I've just gave you a formula to calculate distance between point :) Just check it against 50 or whatever distance you need and you good to go.

Comment: Oh. Thanks! This is so cool, i totally wouldn't think about pythagoras lol. Thanks very much, u and Matthew Watson helped me really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use Pythagoras to compute the distance between the points, and compare it with the range.

Normally you need to square root to find the distance between two points, but if you just need to compare to a range, you can instead square the range and avoid having to take a square root.

For example:

```
static bool isInRange(Point p1, Point p2, int range)
{
    int rangeSquared = range * range;

    int deltaX = p2.X - p1.X;
    int deltaY = p2.Y - p1.Y;

    int distanceSquared = deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY;

    return distanceSquared <= rangeSquared;
}
```

Also note that these calculations will overflow if the coordinates become too big, but this is not going to happen for pixel coords on a screen.

Comment: Thanks, i will totally experiment with it. oh and also, should it be `int deltaY = p2.Y - p1.Y` ?

Comment: @dadasdasdas Yes it should, and thanks to dmitry for correcting the typo.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question it is about determining the distance between two points in a straight line, i.e. the radius of a circle around its center.

For that you'd need the deltas in x and y first. Afterwards you use pythagoras theorem (to be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)).

```
double deltaX = myPos.X - cursorPoint.X;
double deltaY = myPos.Y - cursorPoint.Y;
double distance = Math.Sqrt( Math.Pow( deltaX, 2 ) + Math.Pow( deltaY, 2));
// Continue with your calculations with distance and myRadius
```